# How to display data on app to different users

Tags: database

I have created a app to upload some data given by the user 
But this is visible only to that users device.what should I do to that app,so that the data uploaded by the user is visible to all the users of that app. 
Like I want to add a link to my app daily and I want that link to be seen by all the users of that app.what should I do to make this happen

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: I am not using any data base.....is this possible if we use a database.?

Comment: Iam a beginner... Can you suggest me a link to how to do that

Comment: yeah, It can be solved by using a database. How are you implementing this now?

Comment: I thought to implement using sqlite database..... Can we do that using sqlite and php....?

Comment: yes. It can be done. you can store the data in one table. I can give you a basic structure. You can have two tables. One for users and one for the other data you have. Let's say todos table. when you add a todo with a specific user you can make the respective `todo` row point to the respective user by using `foreign key` or adding a `created_by` field with userId. If you want to fetch the data only added by the current user, you can filter the `todo` table with the respective userId against the `created_by` field. If you want to fetch all the data you don't have to filter.